# Assigning &euro; to arrays

Tags: php, jquery, html, euro

I am working on a website that does not display euro signs properly unless I put $euro; I know this is not ideal but its what  have to work with.

I have an array of prices that is passed to the webpage via a jquery function but if I use $euro; it will print out $euro; rather than € And if I use the € symbol I get a �

Below is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var terms = ["€6 IRELAND", "€15 UK/EUROPE", "€30 INTERNATIONAL"," FREE SHIPPING ON ORDERS OVER €100 (ISLAND OF IRELAND ONLY)"];

function rotateTerm() {
  var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
  $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms[ct]).fadeIn()
              .delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
}
$(rotateTerm);

</script>


<div class="custom_text">SHIPPING RATES: <span id="rotate">this</span></div>
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this?

Comment: have you tried adding something like <meta charset="UTF-8"> to tell browser how to interpret chars?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. where would that go, in the header?

Comment: normally in the `<head>`, yes: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Ya I tried a few different methods like that. Its a wordpress website someone else built so I did not want to spend anymore time on it just trying to find a work around for now.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: In your code there is neither `&euro;` (which you wrote in the header and which would be correct) nor `$euro;` (which you write several times in the text and which would be wrong) - what exactly IS your code?

Comment: Hi, In my question I said "IF" i use $euro; (not that i did use it) because using it in an array takes it literally so it is wrong to use in that respect.
 Everywhere else on the site I can use the $euro; to get the euro symbol but just not here as it is coming in threw in an array which was my problem. Its been answered now anyway Ill just Obi's work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quick work around should do the trick for now while you work on a more elegant solution

```js
var terms = [ "6 IRELAND", "15 UK/EUROPE", "30 INTERNATIONAL"," 100+ ORDERS GETS FREE SHIPPING (ISLAND OF IRELAND ONLY)"];

function rotateTerm() {
  var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
  $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms[ct]).fadeIn()
              .delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
}
$(rotateTerm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom_text">SHIPPING RATES: &#8364;<span id="rotate"></span>    </div>
```

I just employed the HTML EURO Decimal Code €

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Obi! This will do the trick. Appreciate you taking the time to help :)